# Can I call other Echo devices in my house?

Tags: smart-home, alexa

Recently, Amazon introduced [calling](https://techcrunch.com/2017/05/09/amazon-enables-free-calls-and-messages-on-all-echo-devices-with-alexa-calling/) between devices with Alexa Calling. With this, you can ask Alexa to call other people who have Echo devices (and have enabled the feature).

**Is it possible to tell Alexa to call yourself, so that you could use it as an intercom in the house if both devices are linked to the same account?**

Clearly, calling a device on a different account should work, but I couldn't find any authoritative reference confirming that calling between devices on the same account works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible.**

I did some further digging, because I didn't have two Alexa devices at hand, but found some [confirmation on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/6a78bx/using_echo_as_an_intercom/dhcafz1/). The exact mechanics are like so:

- Say "Alexa, call home" to the device that you want to call from
- All other devices connected to the same account ring ([like this](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/1467/12)) and wait for someone to pick up
- When someone says "Alexa, answer", that device picks up the call, and the other devices stop ringing
- You now have an 'intercom' between devices!

The device you're calling from won't ring (obviously), and the support for calling yourself seems good. [Here's a video](https://youtu.be/KItd9zKSF0I?t=226) of someone calling themselves, if you want to see it in action.

Answer (score 4):

The solution you posted should work fine, but if not, there's also a workaround posted on [lovemyecho.com](http://lovemyecho.com/2017/02/14/another-alexa-intercom-life-hack-send-messages-alexa-devices/) that would allow you to use your Amazon Echo as a 1-way intercom, though it doesn't use the calling system.

Basically, you have to follow **these three steps:**

#### 1. Record a custom mp3 file

Basically just record an mp3 of whatever you want to communicate to the people in the other room, ie: "Lunchtime!" or whatever.

#### 2. Upload the mp3 file to Amazon Music

Upload the file in a "Messages Playlist", being sure to use good names: they suggest something like `MSG_something` or something along those lines.

#### 3. Send the message to an Echo / Dot

Go to the Alexa app and choose the message you want to send from the "Music / Books" area.  Having used the `MSG_something` file names and having the files in the playlist should make them easier to find.

---

Obviously, if you want 2-way communication, this would clearly be impracticable, but the advantage of this system is that if there is a message that you frequently want to send, it doesn't require the person on the other end to "pick up the line."