# Custom sensor readings with Amazon Alexa

Tags: smart-home, mqtt, alexa, sensors, node-red

**TLDR:**
I want to query Alexa for the current humidity sensor reading by asking:

> "What is the current humidity, Alexa?"

The answer should be similar to:

> "The current humidity level is 56.7%"

**Here is my setup:**

- I have a bunch of ESP8266 with a variety of sensors, which publish the sensor readings via MQTT over WLAN
- The MQTT broker is running on a Raspberry Pi in the same LAN
- I also have NodeRed running on the Raspberry Pi, where I am using the [Node-RED Alexa Home Skill Bridge](https://alexa-node-red.bm.hardill.me.uk/docs), which works perfectly for sending commands to the different Nodes in my network

**What I am looking for:**

- I would like to be able to ask Alexa for the current sensor reading of any of my sensors and have her answer with the proper value
- In theory I understand that the Node-RED Alexa Home Skill Bridge at least should provide the oppurtunity to query for the temperature reading of a device, when you are in the US/UK.
- However, although I tried, this doesn't seem to work on my German Alexa
- Futhermore, I would of course also prefer to ask Alexa e.g. for the current humidity directly and not having to misuse the temperature query

**Is there any way to achieve what I intend to do, e.g. by using an already existing skill or maybe a NodeRed extension?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alexa does not have any device types that support humidity at the moment, so this is not possible using the Smart Home Skills.<sup>1</sup>

Here is the [list](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/list-of-interfaces.html) of device types and their capabilities.

You could create your own normal skill, but this would mean asking something like "***Alexa, ask FooBar what the humidity is***". There is a [node](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-alexa) for Node-RED to do normal skills but it has been abandoned by it's author for years. You can implement your own just using HTTP-in/HTTP-response nodes, but it's a lot more work.

<sup>1</sup> There is a new capability for Smart Home Skills that allows you to add your own custom commands using a [CustomIntent](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-customintent.html). This is currently only in beta at the moment and would require building a custom Smart Home Skill if allowed on to the beta.

(Author of the Node-RED Alexa Home Skill Nodes)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the different pointers. I guess I will then try my luck with my own custom Alexa skill. Btw. awesome job on the Alexa Home Skill Node!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I was able to achieve my target to be able to query Alexa for custom sensor readings without the need to program my own skill.

---

The following **elements** are used in my setup:

1. A **Raspberry Pi** in my home LAN with **Node-RED** installed on it
2. Some source for a sensor signal (in my case a **Nodemcu** with a **DHT22** sensor that sends the humidity readings via MQTT to the Raspberry Pi, where the **MQTT broker** is running)
3. An **Amazon Echo** (which does not need to be in the same LAN as the Raspberry Pi!)
4. The [**Node-RED Alexa Home Skill Bridge**](https://alexa-node-red.bm.hardill.me.uk/) node by @hardillb
5. The [**Alexa-remote-control shell script**](https://github.com/thorsten-gehrig/alexa-remote-control) that lets you [issue any text-to-speech command to your Alexa devices](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/4022/9008)

---

Here are the **steps** that one needs to take:

1. **Register** a new device in @hardillb’s [Node-RED Alexa Home Skill Bridge](https://alexa-node-red.bm.hardill.me.uk/). Any device and name combination should do. I chose a smart plug and called it “Humidity_at_home”.
2. Now let Alexa **search** for new devices.
3. Create an **Alexa routine** in the Alexa app, where you use a custom voice trigger (in my case: “Alexa, what is the current humidity level”) to switch the virtual device “Humidity_at_home” on.
4. In Node-RED **configure a Alexa Home Skill Bridge node** for the device “Humidity_at_home”. Depending on the command from Alexa (“Humidity_at_home” plug on/off) the `msg.command` element of the node output will have the value `TurnOnRequest`/`TurnOffRequest`.
5. In node-red, when the “Humidity_at_home” node is triggered and outputs `msg.command = "TurnOnRequest"`, call the **Alexa-remote-control shell script** via the **exec node** issuing a text-to-speech command to an Echo device, e.g. using this command:

   ```
   alexa_remote_control.sh -d "Your Echo's name" -e speak:'Here is the text string you construct as answer to your Alexa request for the humidity level value'
   ```

---

Needless to say that you can use any kind of virtual device and any kind of setting of the device to trigger actions in node-red.