# Alexa unprompted

Tags: alexa

My Alexa said something when I got home and no one prompted her, I was the only one here and was in the bathroom, it sounded like she said " what device?" This is the second time I have heard her talk with no one talking to her, I don't know what to think, What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, no, they voted to close because it is "unclear what you are asking". So, maybe you should read [ask]. But, please do ask more questions :-)

Comment: and there is also this question: https://iot.stackexchange.com/q/882/9008 Maybe one of the answers is what happened in your case.

Comment: just a speculation: maybe your phone automatically connected via bluetooth to your echo? I would also suggest to check your voice command history for Alexa in your amazon account. Maybe you find something there.