# Make Alexa, Sonos, or some other speaker to speak, when an email is received

Tags: alexa, ifttt

I would like to have some kind of audible warning when an email arrives to my Gmail inbox (besides the sound of my phone).

Is there any way to make Alexa (or maybe some other speaker) to speak when this trigger happens? It doesn't even have to say anything specific about the email, like the subject. It would be enough to me to say something like "You have new email!"

I am thinking of IFTTT, but if there are other ways, I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, having Alexa say something is not a "that"-action that is available on IFTTT. Therefore, you need to have another approach.

One possible way would be to use Node-red running on e.g. a Raspberry Pi, where you could use the email node to check periodically for new mails in your account.

Once you have the trigger for the arrival of new email, you could trigger the speech output on your Echo device via the [**Alexa-remote-control shell script**](https://github.com/thorsten-gehrig/alexa-remote-control) that lets you [issue any text-to-speech command to your Alexa devices](https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/4022/9008). In case you are using Node-red, the `exec` node will do the trick.

Here would be the syntax for the script in your case:

```
    alexa_remote_control.sh -d "Your Echo's name" -e speak:'You have new mail'
```

Of course, there is no need to use Node-red. You could also do some elaborate shell script for that purpose, using the alexa-remote-control.